# Is it incorrect to create a new instance of a class with a static method on it?

Tags: php, function, static

I was just wondering about the use of the static method in PHP. I have a class that has a public static method.

```
class Dog{
  public static function sound(){
     $bark = "WOOF!";
     return $bark;
  }
}

$new = new Dog(); 
$new->sound();
```

It returns an Fatal Error. 
So when I call this class. I created a new instance, then call it, but it gives me an error. What is the object that it is referring to? and what is the non-object?

Thanks.

Update:
fatal error: Call to a member function on a non-object

Comment: There isn't an `s` in `return`

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: As far as I know, the only error triggered by your code should be "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$bark' (T_VARIABLE)" and its unrelated to OOP. Can you clarify what error you get when you fix the typo?

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://3v4l.org/IkC74). The error complaints about `$new` not being an object!

Comment: There're already like half a dozen answers stating you cannot call a static method with a class instance. Well, it doesn't trigger any error, warning or notice and [the manual](http://es1.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) says you can!

Comment: Is this the whole code? I also couldn't reproduce your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$new->sound();` triggers *Call to a member function on a non-object* it means that you are attempting to call a member function (`sound()`) on something that is not an object (`$new`). That's the real problem and it cannot be triggered by the code you've posted. I'm pretty sure that you get that error in your real code but you've posted a simplified version that doesn't reproduce the issue.

The simplified code you've posted should work just fine, except that of course it doesn't print or use the returned value. With a little fix we can see that both ways to call a static method are valid:

```
<?php

error_reporting(-1);

class Dog{
  public static function sound(){
     $bark = "WOOF!";
     return $bark;
  }
}

$new = new Dog();
echo Dog::sound();
echo $new->sound();
```

See it [in action](http://3v4l.org/r7T6v).

[The manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) might not say it explicitly but implicitly confirms it can be done:

> Declaring class properties or methods as static makes them accessible
> without **needing** an instantiation of the class.
> [...]
> Because static methods **are callable without an instance** of the
> object created, the pseudo-variable $this is not available inside the
> method declared as static.

Not being mandatory is not the same as being forbidden.

> Static **properties** cannot be accessed through the object using the
> arrow operator `->`.

Properties, not methods.

> Calling **non-static** methods statically generates an E_STRICT level
> warning.

That's the opposite thing, which is clearly documented as disallowed

Comment: G. Vicario: wow, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You would access your static method:

```
Dog::sound();
```

If you didn't delare your sound() method static, then it would be:

```
$dog = new Dog();
$dog->sound();
```

So your code could be:

```
class Dog{
    public static function staticSound(){
        $bark = "WOOF!";
        return $bark;
    }

    public function objectSound(){
        $bark = 'Woof';
        return $bark;
    }
}

$dog = new dog(); 
echo $dog->objectSound();
echo Dog::staticSound();
```

Comment: Sadly, PHP doesn't care if you call a static method with a -> as long as the object is instanciated, before PHP version 5.4

Also, in 5.4, it would only produce a strict warning, not a fatal error.

Comment: @MészárosLajos +1, thats true, which does cause me confusion sometimes!

Comment: @Phil Cross: thank you very much. I should use the (::) for that.

Comment: @MészárosLajos - Can you provide code that triggers that strict warning you talk about? I've been unable to get any error, warning or notice.

Comment: Sorry, your code works fine, just tested it under PHP 5.4, I was mixing it when you call a non static method as a static in an instanciated object.

`ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

class Dog{
  public function sound(){
     $bark = "WOOF!";
     return $bark;
  }
}

$new = new Dog(); 
echo $new::sound();`

**Strict standards: Non-static method Dog::sound() should not be called statically**

Comment: @MészárosLajos - Correct, that's the opposite thing which is not allowed because it might not work (e.g. if the method calls `$this`).

Answer (score 2):

Static methods in PHP are called this way:

```
Dog::sound();
```

the difference between static and non-static methods is that a static method doesn't have access to $this variable. Also, static methods are called on a **class** and not on an **instance** of that class.

Note: You only get a fatal error because you have a typo in the return statement - your syntax would accually work, because PHP is very forgivable, and would **allow** to call a static method in a non-static way.

Comment: I see. That made more sense. :)

Comment: Static methods can also be called on a class instance. There's nothing that prevent that from working.

Answer (score 1):

It is okay to create an instance of a class that implements a static method.

It is just illegal to call that method statically.

to call the static method you would use

```
Dog::sound();
```

And in `Dog::sound` `$this` would not be available because you are calling it on the class as opposed to an instance.

For a bonus static methods can also be invoked by:

from within the class as

```
self::sound();
static::sound();
```

From an extend class as

```
static::sound();
```

From Anywhere as

```
$a = array("Dog","sound");
$a();

call_user_func($a);

$d= "Dog"; $s = "Sound";
$d::$s();

$d = new Dog();
$d->sound();
```

Comment: What exactly makes `$new->sound()` illegal?

Comment: In php 5.4 it generates a warning

Comment: Can you reproduce that in the PHP fiddle of your choice?

Comment: I was wrong... the warning i was thinking of is if you call a non-static function in a static context.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you have to invoke static methods on the class, not on an instance. This actually varies per OOP-language - some do allow this, so the confusion is understandable, but the reason PHP doesn't is simply because it doesn't have strong typing, thus not allowing the compiler to safely determine the type of `$dog` during the invocation.

The correct syntax is `Dog::sound()`.

Comment: You have to? The manual doesn't say so and if you use it it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the static method from an instance like this:

```
$dog = new Dog();
$dog::sound();
```

But you should call static methods like this

```
Dog::sound();
```

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: `$new->sound()` works just fine. Try it!

Comment: Yes, it seems to work since PHP 5.0.0. But I dont't think it can be considered good programming style. Also it's not backwards compatible with PHP versions lower than 5.0.0.

Comment: If I recall correctly, methods could not be explicitly defined as static [before PHP/5](http://es1.php.net/manual/en/oop4.php). So I'd say that `$new->sound()` has been valid since OOP reached PHP ;-)

Comment: Yes, you're right. My fault.

Answer (score -3):

You can't call a static method on an instantiated object you must call it in your example like that :

```
Dog.sound();
```

It's the way static method are used on most of the langage

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php

Comment: @user2417992: Hi, what is the object that it is referring to? i am  new to classes that's all. thanks.

Comment: @mishu: that's what I thought, some of you will refer me to php.net. I  asked it here because answers are simpler.

Comment: It doesn't refer to an object... it is static to the class meaning it doesn't have access to any instance methods or properties.

Comment: @ladybug I did not refer you to php.net, I posted that because the answer was wrong, static methods are called using the scope resolution operator ( :: )

Comment: As your method is static you can call it from where ever you want without you have to make o new instance of the class so if you have a class A with a static method b() you will always call it by A.b(), or in php A::b()